# specific array values into another array typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-5

```
 "info": [
    {
        "Name": "sda",
        "Icon": null,
        "id": 45
    },
    {
        "Name": "srda",
        "Icon": null,
        "id": 47 
    }]
```

i have an array of this json body / model class  .
I need to put only ids into another array in typescript.

Comment: I'm guessing it's a duplicate, anyway just use map funciton of array: https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: @HalilÇakar I think I found a good duplicate

Comment: @Esdras - please specify the expected output format and an example values.

Comment: @RahulBhobe "I need to put only ids into another array"

Comment: yes - but OP does not specify what format. `[45, 47]` or `[{id: 45}, {id: 47}]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` operator for this

```js
var el={
"info": [
    {
        "Name": "sda",
        "Icon": null,
        "id": 45
    },
    {
        "Name": "srda",
        "Icon": null,
        "id": 47 
    }]
}
var result=el.info.map(x=>x.id);
console.log(result);
```